# Maintain Selection State After Changing Backend Collection in ListView

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a listview control that is bound to an observable collection that I frequently update. When I update the collection, I clear the collection and then add the values. While this is a bit overkill for simple changes, it's very simple and accomplishes the job. In doing so, I lose which item was selected in my listview control and cannot figure out how to maintain the selected state after an update.

I initially thought I could two-way bind the SelectedValue by using the following (WPF):

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedDevice, Mode=TwoWay}
```

And then update my collection by:

```
string PreviouslySelectedDevice = this.SelectedDevice;
aCollection.Clear();
// ... Add Items ...
this.SelectedDevice = PreviouslySelectedDevice;
```

I was hoping the TwoWay binding would allow me to make changes to backend property which would be automagically reflected in the listView control but this doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your binding should be updating `SelectedValue`.  Is `SelectedDevice` a `DependencyProperty` or are you implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: SelectedDevice is a KeyValuePair<int,string> that stores the selected device (SelectedDevice ID, SelectedDevice Name). I suspect the problem is that since KeyValuePair doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, the control isn't being updated as I intended.

Comment: It would be the class which has the SelectedDevice property that would need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, or the SelectedDevice property would need to be a DependencyProperty.